# Animate scale of ContentControl

Tags: wpf, animation

I am trying to animate Scale X and Y property of ContentControl. This is my code:

//MainWindow constructor:

```
        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(0, 0);
        ModalControl.LayoutTransform = scale;
        ModalControl.UpdateLayout();
```

// animation code

```
        Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> {
            var anim = new DoubleAnimation {
                From = 0,
                To = 1,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)
            };

            var scaleXAnim = new DoubleAnimation {
                From = 0,
                To = 1,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)
            };

            ModalControl.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, anim); // this works
            ModalControl.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, scaleXAnim); // this doesn't
            ModalControl.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, scaleXAnim);

            Console.WriteLine("Animation called");

        });
```

XAML

```
    <ContentControl x:Name="ModalControl" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="100" Visibility="Visible" Opacity="0"  Content="{StaticResource ModalElement}" Background="Red">
```

I am not sure what am I missing. When animation opacity it works as expected, but Scale is more troublesome. Any ideas what else needs to be done?

Comment: It's unclear why you start the animations in a Dispatcher action. Seems pointless, at least in the context of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control does not have the ScaleX and ScaleY property.

You have to animate the properties of the ScaleTransform object in the control's LayoutTransform:

```
ModalControl.LayoutTransform.BeginAnimation(
    ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, scaleXAnim);

ModalControl.LayoutTransform.BeginAnimation(
    ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, scaleXAnim);
```